# How to write unit test to this method

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testing, methods

I have such an example of method:

```
class Class(OtherClass):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

or the second example:

```
class Class():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

I have no idea how to write a unit test to verify it.
I have experience only in classic functions like:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: can you give a bit more details about what you want to test in those class? This is to vague: show some code!

Answer (score 1):

You have just written a class definition with a single method, which is called when the class is instantiated. So a unit test could be if you can instantiate the object and check if its attribute is correct.

```
testx = 'something'
assert Class(testx).x == testx
```